# PUT method in playframework FunctionalTest

Tags: playframework

I wrote a little application using GAE and the playframework.

I am trying to test the PUT method (used for updates) and when called
from a FunctionalTest it always returns with the login page even
though I login at the beginning of the test, that can be confirmed by
all the other method working fine.

It looks like when using the PUT method the session is lost

Anybody had similar problems?

I'm using play 1.1.1

Comment: Hi, we need a bit more detail: what code are you using to call the put, your routes entry, the implementation of the method, if put works outside the tests, etc. As much info as you can provide please :)

Comment: Are you testing on your localhost or on the deployed GAE? Do you get any difference between the two? I know that GAE does not support many of the Play core features, and I wondering if this is one of those features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in FunctionalTest.
In all the methods (POST, GET, DELETE) there is the following line that carries over the cookies

```
if (savedCookies != null) request.cookies = savedCookies;
```

This line is missing in PUT. Also because savedCookies is private you can't access it in your tests.

The work around is to define the cookies map in your test as a private variable, set it to the login response cookies and then call POST with a new request using this cookies.

Here is my code

```
private static Map<String, Http.Cookie> lastCookies;

public void login(){
    String postUrl = Router.reverse("GAEActions.doLogin").url;
    Map<String, String> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("email", "as@gmail.com");
    map.put("url", "/");
    map.put("isAdmin", "true");
    Map<String, File> fileMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    Response post = POST(postUrl, map, fileMap);
    lastCookies = post.cookies;
}
public void test(){
....
    Request request = newRequest();
    request.cookies = lastCookies;
    Response post = PUT(request, url,"application/json",json);
```